# Highest power of given primen number in all binomial coefficients of n

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Given prime number p and integer n, for what value of i where 0$\leq$i$\leq$n, the highest of p in ${n \choose i}$ occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) on binomial coefficients tells you that the exponent of $p$ occurring in ${n \choose i}$ is the number of carries when adding $n-i$ to $i$ in base $p$.  So you want to choose $i$ to maximize this number of carries.  The maximum number of carries will occur with $i = p^m-1$
where $p^m \le n < p^{m+1}$ (this generally won't be the only solution).